# Resgen a folder of .resources files to .resx?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How can I convert a folder of .resources files to .resx? I don't want to have to manually convert each file.

Answer (score 0):

only from file to file throught ResGen.exe

Comment: Is there a way with a batch command to have it call it with each .resources file in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

this a old thread, but search point here.
Use Visual Studio command prompt (like "x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022") to set path for resgen.exe, that can be found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A or ..\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools".

In command prompt, type the "dir" command, in the generated project folder, as:
"dir *.resources /B > convToRes.bat"; in each line of convToRes.bat, for example, "projectname.formName.resource" change to
"resgen projectname.formName.resource formName.resx"

I think this is good way.